# correctly escaping characters when generating dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWEC8/):**

```
function Start() {

    var TheData = 'tes"ss<div></div>t3\'k';

    var TheHTML = '<div class="SomeClass">' + TestXSS(TheData) + '</div>';
    TheHTML += '<input type="text" id="TheTextBox" value="';
    TheHTML += TestXSS(TheData) + '" />';

    $('#Dynamic').html(TheHTML);
}

function TestXSS(TheText) {

    TheText = TheText.replace('"', '&quot;');
    TheText = TheText.replace("'", '&#39;');
    TheText = TheText.replace('<', '&lt;');
    TheText = TheText.replace('>', '&gt;');

    return TheText;
}
```

As you can see, the HTML is dynamically generated and added to the DOM with jQuery, and there's also a function to escape characters that might cause problems. But in the fiddle, there's still an issue and so I was wondering how to correctly escape characters.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function TestXSS(TheText) {

    TheText = TheText.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    TheText = TheText.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
    TheText = TheText.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    TheText = TheText.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

    return TheText;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K3mCp/)

Comment: Awesome!!! This works and fixes a big problem I've been struggling with; thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
TheText.replace('"', '&quot;'); // stops after first match
```

use `g` modifier for global match

```
TheText = TheText.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
```

The `g` modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reducing the number of (unnecessary) calls to `replace()`, and using a regular expression in concert with a map:

```
function TestXSS(TheText) {
    var charMap = {
        39 : '&#39',
        34 : '&quot',
        60 : '&lt;',
        62 : '&gt;'
    }
    return TheText.replace(new RegExp("['\"<>]",'g'), function(a){
        return charMap[a.charCodeAt(0)] || '';
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wWEC8/5/).

References:

- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).